# Mobx store has data, but when passed as props - it's becomes undefined

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have top level React component - App.js - which simplified is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { appStore } from './state/appStore';
import CartPage from './pages/CartPage';
export default function App() {
  console.log('STORE IN APP:', appStore);
  return <CartPage store={ appStore } />;
};
```

And CartPage is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const CartPage = observer((props) => {
  const { store } = props;
  console.log('STORE IN CART: ', store);
  ...
});
```

In `<App />` the console.log correctly shows the data in the store, but in `<CartPage />` - I get no such thing as `store` ... ?

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: I was pressed by the time so I searched for another solution and when I tried zustand - it worked fine. Also the transition from mobx was flawless.